# How to print out $0(script name) in front of the exit-status?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Hei, I need help with how to print script name infront of exit status.

For instance my script name is  myprog.sh and in it I have written exit 123. So when I run the script and then type command echo $?  it should print out: myprog 123

"Change the program so that it prints the 0(zeroth) argument in front of the error message that you have programmed."

I have tried different methods but nothing have worked so far, so some help or guidance would be nice. I think i have to use $0 which prints the script name.

my program is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 1 ]    
then  
  echo " Total arguments for program is equal to 1"  
else         
  echo " not equal to 1"   
  exit 123    
fi
```

Comment: Your quote in the post says _"prints the 0(zeroth) argument in front of the error message"_, while in the title you ask to print it in "front of the exit-status". So what's the expected output? Something like `myprog.sh: error: this and that happened` would be the usual way to print error messages, what e.g. Bash does. If you really mean to print the exit status, and something before it, then _what_ exit status should it be? It can't be the script's own exit status, since after it's exited, it can't print anything. Or are you expecting a message like `myprog.sh: ls exited with status 1`?

Comment: there is no such thing as zeroth anything ... the lowest reference is `first` ... there is such a thing as index value of zero which points to the first item or item zero

Comment: `echo $?` has to be aliased for a custom script that knows the correlation between exit status and last process/program (which is afaik not possible)

Answer (score 1):

The exit status is an integer: see [3.7.5 Exit Status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status) in the manual.

Read your requirements carefully:

> Change the program so that it prints the 0(zeroth) argument in front of the ***error message*** that you have programmed